# Consulta php y ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un formulario con un input tipo `text` y un botón `submit` donde escribo un código de producto y busco en una base de datos MySQL.

Los resultados los muestro en una tabla dentro de la misma página, pero ¿Cómo hago para que al presionar el botón buscar no se recargue la página?  Tengo este código:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST["btnBuscar"])) {
        $prod = new Productos();
        $cod = $_POST["txtCodProd"];
        $data = $prod->getProdByCod($cod);
        $var = '';

        if(!empty($data)){
            foreach ($data as $i=>$v) { ?>
              <tr>
                <?php $var .= "<td>".$v."</td>";
                 ?>

              </tr>
            <?php
                }
                echo "<tr>".$var."</tr>";
             ?>
    </table>
        <?php
        }else{
            echo 'No hay resultados.';
            }
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

El controlador Productos tiene esta función:

```
public function getProdByCod($cod){
        $p = new ProductosMySqlDAO();
        $res = $s->load($cod);
        return $res;
    }
```

Y el modelo:

```
    public function load($id){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigoproducto = ?';
        $sqlQuery = new SqlQuery($sql);
        $sqlQuery->setNumber($id);
        return $this->getRow($sqlQuery);
    }

    protected function getRow($sqlQuery){
        $tab = QueryExecutor::execute($sqlQuery);
        if(count($tab)==0){
            return null;
        }
        return $this->readRow($tab[0]);     
    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacer esa consulta con jquery?

Comment: Estas usando jquery?. Porque podrias llamar a una funcion ajax con jquery y recargar la parte que quieres

Comment: me gustaria usarlo, pero no se como aplicarlo a este caso

Answer (score 1):

```
var codigo = $("input[name=codigo]").val();
$.get( "buscar.php", { codigo_producto: codigo } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    // data deberia ser un json (buscar.php debe retornar un json)
    alert( "Datos: " + data );
    // foreach de los datos, con la funcion append de jquery
    // puedes agregar facilmente items por medio de un id que le asignes a la tabla.
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      $("#table").append(/* aqui el <tr></tr>*/);
    });​
});
```

Usa jquery y estructura bien el JSON que devuelvas en buscar.php